# Permutations list repeating itself when returning ArrayList in toString method

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist

*SOLVED: Wasn't clearing out the ArrayList ebwteen calls, so the list kept incrementing. I added perm.clear() before the 2nd for loop in nextPermutation(), and problem solved! Thanks to all who helped.

I'm having trouble returning an ArrayList within a toString method. My assignment is to generate 10 lists of permutations from the number 1-10. The method nextPermutation is called 10 times in the driver.

I want my output to look like this:

```
List 1: [4 6 8 1 9 7 10 5 3 2]
List 2: [6 8 1 7 3 4 9 10 5 2]
```

etc..

Instead, each new list keeps the permutation from the last list while adding a new permutation, so I get this:

```
List 1:  [6, 2, 3, 9, 4, 5, 10, 8, 7, 1]
List 2:  [6, 2, 3, 9, 4, 5, 10, 8, 7, 1, 3, 7, 2, 9, 1, 10, 6, 4, 8, 5]
```

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class PermutationGenerator {
    Random rand;
    ArrayList<Integer> perm = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public PermutationGenerator(int s) {
        rand = new Random(s);
    }

    public void nextPermutation() {
        ArrayList<Integer> myArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            myArrayList.add(i);
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            int a = rand.nextInt(myArrayList.size());
            perm.add(myArrayList.get(a));
            myArrayList.remove(a);
        }
    }

    public final String toString() {
        return perm.toString();
    }
}
```

I was able to get the correct output by changing the void nextPermutation() method to ArrayList, returning perm inside the method, and taking out the ArrayList from the field and placing it in the nextPermutation method. However, for the assignment I need nextPermutation to be void and I also need a toString method.

So, my question is, how do I return perm within toString and get one permutation per list?

Comment: You're just adding ints to `perm` and you never clear it for the next time you call `nextPermutation()`.  Do you want an `ArrayList<List>` maybe?  I understand the question, but not what you're trying to do with your code.. Can you show a main method that drives the population of `perm`?

Comment: When debugging something like this and you see that you have the same result from the previous call added to the result of next call, it should signal to you that your data structure may not be cleared out between calls.

Comment: Yep, that was the case, used perm.clear() to help fix that. I'll add this solution to the OP in case anyone else has the same problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you need to clear perm each time after printing it and before the next call to `nextPermutation()`, or have `nextPermutation()` create and return a list which gets printed and then thrown away.

If you keep adding to the same list, it's just going to grow and grow.

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much, I just checked out how to clear an ArrayList and then just used perm.clear() before the second for loop in nextPermutation(). Works perfectly. Thanks again!

Comment: Done! Sorry, new user. :)