# How do I fill an array in my main class with a fillPermutation void method?

Tags: java

My RandomPermutation class and fillPermutation method:

```
public class RandomPermutation 
{
    public int permutation[]; 
    private int numAttempts[];


    public void fillPermutation(int numItems, int seed)
    {

        if (permutation.length!=numItems)
            permutation = new int[numItems];
        Random rand = new Random(seed);
        permutation[0]=rand.nextInt(numItems-1);
        numAttempts[0]=1; 

        for(int i=1; i<numItems-1; i++)
        {
            int count = 0;
            int m=rand.nextInt(numItems);
            for(int j=0; j<i-1; j++)
                while(m==permutation[j])
                {
                    m=rand.nextInt(numItems);
                    count++;
                }   
            permutation[i]=m;
            numAttempts[i]=count;
        }   
    }
}
```

Requirements for the main class:

"Initially, main-function should call fill-function once for numItems = 10, and print the permutation and the numAt- tempts as shown below. You would also want to print the integers m as they are created in the process, but turn the printing of m off before generating the second part of the output; save the outputs in some file. Then, add the call averNumAttempts with numItems = 10 and numIterationss = 100000 in main-function to generate the second part of the output and save it at the end of the first output file. Finally, submit paper copy of your code and the output file."

So how do I make this work using a void method? There's a bit more info on the assignment sheet about the other parts of the code if anybody needs clarification.

Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: I could have sworn I was just working on this question 10 minutes ago... Maybe it was just a _really_ similar one.

Comment: I think you mean this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21317074/permutations-list-repeating-itself-when-returning-arraylist-in-tostring-method sounds like the same assignment to me too

Comment: Ahh, that's the one! My mistake. Sorry @user3092589. Do see my confusion though?

Comment: Not the same assignment, I'm not allowed to use arraylists. But I think I've got it guys. He didn't specify to make a constructor in the RandomPermutation class, but I think that it's the only way to make it work.

Comment: The same way you'd do it with a `justDoSomething` void method.